# What is the sample distribution of DFBETA in linear regression?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, diagnostic

I am wondering in which way the threshold of determining statistical significance for DFBETA is computed. From the famous book "Regression Diagnostics: Identifying Influential Data and Sources of Collinearity", it seems the derivation is not rigorous and is just a "suggestion". And I cannot see why the suggestion (-2 and +2) is reasonable. Would anybody help me clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know where you're getting (-2,+2) from. Everywhere I'm poking around lists the standard cutoff as 2/sqrt(n). I'm only seeing this discussed as a heuristic so I can't provide any insight into how that value was arrived at, but I wanted to comment that the cutoff you described is different from what seems to be the standard.

Comment: From looking at a formula for DFBETA, I doubt there is a closed form for the sampling distribution. If we assume the coefficients are asymptomatically normal, you could derive an asymptomatic distribution by finding the asymptomatic mean and variance of DFBETA, which itself will require several assumptions about the distribution of the model matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am just confused: 1. the book is famous, it has been cited so many times; 2. the cut-offs are derived from such a nonrigorous way. My confusion is that I have never seen anything like this in Statistics before --- it is so popular and non-rigorous, that is the assumptions are even not clear.

Comment: Here's an idea: what does a Monte-Carlo simulation reveal about DFBETA's distribution?

Comment: @Jim this sounds fun, and I'm going to try to get to it this evening if I have time

Comment: @ user112758 could you post the equations in question? I'm afraid I don't have the book